# Determinant always equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I just finished writing a computer program that takes as input a number of matrices and computes the inverse of the product of matrices.

To test this program, I wanted to input a $3 \times 2$ matrix followed by a $2\times 3$ matrix so that the product would be a $3\times 3$ matrix. No matter how hard I try, the determinant of the product turns out to be zero and so the product is non-invertible. Is there a theorem in linear algebra that implies that the product of a $3\times 2$ matrix and $2\times 3$ matrix will always have determinant zero?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

If you consider a matrix $A$ as a linear mapping $v \mapsto Av$ then a square matrix has determinant different from zero if and only if the mapping is invertible. The product of matrices represents the composition of linear mappings. But for a composition to be invertible, it is required that the first mapping is injective. However a linear mapping from $3$D space to $2$D space cannot be injective...

**added:** alternative proof. Let $A$ be your $3\times 2$ matrix and $B$ the $2\times 3$ matrix so that $AB$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. Now consider the $3\times 3$ matrices $A'$ and $B'$ constructed by adding a column of zeros to $A$ and a row of zeros to $B$. Then notice that $A'B'=AB$ because in the row-by-column multiplication in $A'B'$ you get the row-by-column multiplication in $AB$ plus a $0\cdot 0$. Now you know that $\det A'=\det B'=0$ hence $\det AB = \det A'B' = \det A' \det B' = 0$.

Comment: Does that suggest that $m > n \rightarrow |A^{m X  n} B^{n X m}| = 0 $?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner to linear algebra and don't know about mappings. Would you be able to explain why the determinant is zero without using mappings?

Comment: If you're a programmer, it might be easiest (although not complete) to think of a "mapping" as a function in a computer program that takes the input and "maps" it to the output.  In this case, for A to have a determinant that's not zero, it's function must have an inverse (that is, some function that "undoes" it) - however, the two other functions you've used to create A do not have inverses. As a result, A does not have an inverse. Since it does not have an inverse, the determinant must be zero.

Comment: @kleineg I believe so.

Comment: @Thomas: see the added part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Let's call $A$,$B$ and $M$ your matrix, $M=AB$.

$B$ is not square so it exists $(\lambda_{i})$ non all null such that $\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_{i} C_{i}(B) =0$

You have $\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_{i} C_{i}(M) = \sum\limits_{i} \lambda_{i} A* C_{i}(B) = A*(\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_{i} C_{i}(B)) = 0 $

Comment: what is $C_i(B)$?

Comment: i th column of B

Answer (score 1):

Classical explanation is based on the fact that if we have $m \times n$ matrix  $A$ (with more rows than columns - number for rows can be treated as the number of components of a vector, number of columns as the number of vectors) then vector $w=Av$ , where $v$ is $n \times 1$ vector, must lie in the column space of $A$ $        ($denoted $C(A)$).

In the case of matrix $3 \times 2$ it is a plane in $R^3$.

Now we have $2 \times 3$ matrix  $B$ consisting of three columns $b_1, b_2, b_3$ so the matrix $AB=[ Ab_1 \ \  Ab_2 \ \ Ab_3]$ where every column of the $3 \times 3$ $AB$ lies in the mentioned earlier plane.

So we have **three** vectors lying in the 2-d plane located in 3-d space (evidently they can't be linearly independent) therefore the matrix $AB$ must be singular.

Comment: By classical I mean here an approach given by profesor Gilbert Strang in his lectures (available online) about fundamental 4 subspaces..